# d3.select(#elementId) doesn't find a element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i haven't many experience with javascript.

this is my js code:

```
 function () {


            alert("start");
            var svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

            svg1.setAttributeNS(null,"id","fillgauge1");
            svg1.setAttributeNS(null,"width","97%");
            svg1.setAttributeNS(null,"height","250");
            svg1.setAttributeNS(null,"onclick","gauge1.update(NewValue());");
            document.body.appendChild(svg1);
            var gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 55);
 //other code
  }

 function loadLiquidFillGauge(elementId, value, config) {
     alert("start loadLiquidFillGauge OK");
     if(config == null) config = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
     alert(elementId + "<-elementID| value->" + value + "| config--> " + config );
     var gauge = d3.select("#" + elementId);

     //other code
 }
```

the code stops his execution at the d3.select call.

Do you have some idea about why the elementid fillgauge1 it is not found by the select method?

**EDIT**

i updated the code, now the element svg1 with id fillgauge1 isnt null. but the select method stops the execution yet..

Comment: all the svg1.setAttributeNS calls are wrong. SVG attributes are never in the SVG namespace, they are in the null namespace. You can use setAttribute and omit the namespace if you want or if you insist on setAttributeNS pass null as the first argument.

Comment: i correct all the errror but select doesn't work yet..

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the SVG element to the document. Your SVG is created, but it doesn't exist on the page so the `d3.select` will not work. Add the line below before calling loadLiquidFillGauge.

```
document.body.appendChild(svg1)
```

This may be more clear:

```
 var svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
 svg1.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","id","fillgauge1");
 svg1.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","width","97%");
 svg1.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","height","250");
 svg1.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","onclick","gauge1.update(NewValue());");

 document.body.appendChild(svg1);

 var gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 55);
```

Comment: You should correct all the invalid setAttributeNS calls too really.

Comment: what do you mean for the invalid setAttributeNS?

I add the document.appendChile as your suggestion, but the id "fillgauge1" is already null. 
I don't understand which namespace i have to set in the setAtributeNS method..